# In MVC/Razor, how can you open a new view instead of as a partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a MVC project with Razor.  There is a view with a partial view on the page.  I have a button within the partial view that updates the partial view.  This works fine.  However, I have another button in the view that I want to open a new view; to "break out" of the original view.  Instead, this new view opens where the partial page should be. How can I "break out" of the parent view to open a new view?

This come out of my previous question: [How do I get my MVC page to post to the same action in IE and Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263628/how-do-i-get-my-mvc-page-to-post-to-the-same-action-in-ie-and-chrome)

Here are the details.  I have a view with a partial view.  Clicking on the ButtonB gets some data from the database; everything works fine there.

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                                               |
| MerchantApplicationSummary.cshtml             |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|    PartialDiv                                 |
|    -----------------------------------        |
|    | ApplicationReportPartial.cshtml |        |
|    |                                 |        |
|    |  [Button B]                     |        |
|    -----------------------------------        |
|                                               |
|    [Button A]                                 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When I click on Button A, I want to open a brand new view:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                                               |
| PrintApplication.cshtml                       |
|                                               |
|                                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Instead, I get the view opening up where the partial view was:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|                                               |
| MerchantApplicationSummary.cshtml             |
|                                               |
|                                               |
|    PartialDiv                                 |
|    -----------------------------------        |
|    | PrintApplication.cshtml         |        |
|    |                                 |        |
|    -----------------------------------        |
|                                               |
|    [Button A]                                 |
|                                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I think this behavior comes from setting the UpdateTargetId to output the partial page inside a div on the original page.  I need this so ApplicationReportPartial opens in the correct spot.

MerchantApplicationSummary.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "PartialDiv" }))
{
   ...
   <div id="PartialDiv">
   @{
      Html.RenderPartial("ApplicationReportPartial");
    }
  </div>
  ...
}
```

Here's the controller which checks if it came from button A or button B:

AdminController.cs

```
    [AuthorizeAdmin]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MerchantApplicationSummary(string[] ints, FormCollection form, int? page, string submit)
    {
      if (ints != null && (submit == "Print Spanish Application(s)" || submit == "Print Application(s)"))
      {
        return View(@"~/Views/Admin/PrintApplication.cshtml");
      }
    else
    {
      ...
     return PartialView("ApplicationReportPartial", obj_MrntApp);
    }
```

How do I keep it so that the ApplicationReportPartial opens within MerchantApplicationSummary, but so that PrintApplication opens in a new view?

Edit:

Here's the code for button A:

```
<input id="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Application(s)" />
```

I actually did have button A as a action link, but I needed it to make it a submit button to pass along certain values.  Here's the action again:

```
public ActionResult MerchantApplicationSummary(string[] ints, FormCollection form, int? page, string submit)
```

I need the values of ints when I click on button A; ints is an array of the IDs of checkboxes checked on the page.  If I use an action link, how would I pass along those values to the action?  -- I did some research and it look like this is not possible (see http://forums.asp.net/t/1470988.aspx?HTML+ActionLink+to+post) so this brings me back to my original question of how to "break out" of the parent view.

Comment: Show us the client side code for button A.

Comment: But the basic answer is: don't use AJAX for button A, just use a simple link and let the browser navigate to `/PrintApplication`.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen.  I added the code to my original question.  How do I use a link to PrintApplication and still pass along the values from the view?  I expanded on this in my edit to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the following:
- In the parent view, I used BeginForm instead of Ajax.BeginForm and left off the UpdateTargetId assignment.
- In the controller, returned a View for the partial view instead of a partial view.

MerchantApplicationSummary.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MerchantApplicationSummary", "Admin"))
{
 ...
 <div id="PartialDiv">
   @{
      Html.RenderPartial("ApplicationReportPartial");
    }
 </div>
 ...
 <input id="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Print Application(s)" />
}
```

AdminController.cs

```
[AuthorizeAdmin]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MerchantApplicationSummary(string[] ints, FormCollection form, int? page, string submit, string PrintApplications)
{
  if (ints != null && (submit == "Print Spanish Application(s)" || submit == "Print Application(s)"))
  {
    ...
    return View(@"~/Views/Admin/PrintApplication.cshtml");
  }
  else
  {
    ...
    return View(obj_MrntApp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a standard form submission and return a redirect response.

**MerchantApplicationSummary.cshtml**

```
@(Html.BeginForm("PrintApplication", "Admin", FormMethod.Post)) {
    ...
    <button type="submit" id="buttonA">Print</button>
}
```

And your controller will be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PrintApplication(FormCollection form)
{
    // do stuff with form
    ...
    // stash data you need in redirected view
    TempData["PrintApplication.Id"] = id;

    return RedirectToAction("PrintApplication");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PrintApplication()
{
    int? id = TempData["PrintApplication.Id"] as int?;
    ViewBag.Id = id.Value;
    return View("PrintApplication");
}
```

You submit the form and the RedirectToAction returns a `302 Found` to the browser and it will redirect to the `GET PrintApplication` action.

The messy part here is if you need to share the form with your `MerchantApplicationSummary` AJAX post. It's probably easiest to drop the `AjaxHelper`.

```
<div id="appForms">
 @(Html.BeginForm("PrintApplication", "ControllerName",
                  FormMethod.Post), new { id = "formId" }) {

    <div id="PartialDiv">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("ApplicationReportPartial"); }
    </div>
    ...
    <button type="submit" id="buttonA">Print</button>
 }
</div>
```

Then wire up the button B to trigger a jquery AJAX post. Make sure button B is not a submit button (e.g. `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">`).

```
$("#appForms").on("click", "#buttonB", function(event) {
    var data = $("#formId").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/MerchantApplicationSummary",
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(partialViewResult) {
            $("#PartialDiv").html(partialViewResult);
        }
    });
});
```

Then remove all `PrintApplication` logic from `MerchantApplicationSummary`.

I don't know enough of your specifics so you probably need to do some adjustments here.